# Using Bulk Insert dramatically slows down processing?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm fairly new to Oracle but I have used the Bulk insert on a couple other applications. Most seem to go faster using it but I've had a couple where it slows down the application. This is my second one where it slowed it down significantly so I'm wondering if I have something setup incorrectly or maybe I need to set it up differently. In this case I have a console application that processed ~1,900 records. Inserting them individually it will take ~2.5 hours and when I switched over to the Bulk insert it jumped to 5 hours.

The article I based this off of is http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2009/09-sep/o59odpnet-085168.html

Here is what I'm doing, I'm retrieving some records from the DB, do calculations, and then write the results out to a text file. After the calculations are done I have to write those results back to a different table in the DB so we can look back at what those calculations later on if needed.

When I make the calculation I add the results to a List. Once I'm done writing out the file I look at that List and if there are any records I do the bulk insert.

With the bulk insert I have a setting in the App.config to set the number of records I want to insert. In this case I'm using 250 records. I assumed it would be better to limit my in memory arrays to say 250 records versus the 1,900. I loop through that list to the count in the App.config and create an array for each column. Those arrays are then passed as parameters to Oracle.

App.config

```
<add key="UpdateBatchCount" value="250" />
```

Class

```
class EligibleHours
{
    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public decimal Hours { get; set; }
    public string HoursSource { get; set; }
}
```

Data Manager

```
public static void SaveEligibleHours(List<EligibleHours> listHours)
{            
    //set the number of records to update batch on from config file Subtract one because of 0 based index
    int batchCount = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UpdateBatchCount"]);


    //create the arrays to add values to
    string[] arrEmployeeId = new string[batchCount];
    decimal[] arrHours = new decimal[batchCount];
    string[] arrHoursSource = new string[batchCount];

    int i = 0;
    foreach (var item in listHours)
    {
        //Create an array of employee numbers that will be used for a batch update.
        //update after every X amount of records, update. Add 1 to i to compensated for 0 based indexing.
        if (i + 1 <= batchCount)
        {
            arrEmployeeId[i] = item.EmployeeID;
            arrHours[i] = item.Hours;
            arrHoursSource[i] = item.HoursSource;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            UpdateDbWithEligibleHours(arrEmployeeId, arrHours, arrHoursSource);

            //reset counter and array
            i = 0;
            arrEmployeeId = new string[batchCount];
            arrHours = new decimal[batchCount];
            arrHoursSource = new string[batchCount];
        }
    }

    //process last array
    if (arrEmployeeId.Length > 0)
    {
        UpdateDbWithEligibleHours(arrEmployeeId, arrHours, arrHoursSource);
    }

}


private static void UpdateDbWithEligibleHours(string[] arrEmployeeId, decimal[] arrHours, string[] arrHoursSource)
{
    StringBuilder sbQuery = new StringBuilder();
    sbQuery.Append("insert into ELIGIBLE_HOURS ");
    sbQuery.Append("(EMP_ID, HOURS_SOURCE, TOT_ELIG_HRS, REPORT_DATE) ");
    sbQuery.Append("values ");
    sbQuery.Append("(:1, :2, :3, SYSDATE) ");


    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Server_Connection"].ToString();
    using (OracleConnection dbConn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
    {
        dbConn.Open();

        //create Oracle parameters and pass arrays of data
        OracleParameter p_employee_id = new OracleParameter();
        p_employee_id.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Char;
        p_employee_id.Value = arrEmployeeId;

        OracleParameter p_hoursSource = new OracleParameter();
        p_hoursSource.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Char;
        p_hoursSource.Value = arrHoursSource;

        OracleParameter p_hours = new OracleParameter();
        p_hours.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Decimal;
        p_hours.Value = arrHours;


        OracleCommand objCmd = dbConn.CreateCommand();
        objCmd.CommandText = sbQuery.ToString();
        objCmd.ArrayBindCount = arrEmployeeId.Length;
        objCmd.Parameters.Add(p_employee_id);
        objCmd.Parameters.Add(p_hoursSource);
        objCmd.Parameters.Add(p_hours);

        objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a file to this process anyway? You don't even need the code, you could create a stored procedure to do all this internally on the database. I bet it will be way faster than your approach. I'm suggesting this base on what you wrote. Without knowing the requirements I may be wrong.

Comment: Also 1900 records is nothing in terms of processing batches. Unless there are multiples tables, foreign keys, triggers and other objects as such.

Comment: I might look at a stored proc but I've never done one in Oracle before so I'll have to look up some examples. I come from a MS SQL Server background where I used Stored Procs all the time but the company where I'm at now seems to only use in-line SQL. I've been trying to use Entity Framework where I can which is what I was using to insert the records individually.

Comment: The syntax is a little bit different but the structure is the same from SQL Server to Oracle. This process really should be done inside the database without any external language. And if this process is done repeatedly you can also create a job so it can run by itself with a configured time frame window. You could create a proof of concept to show to your bosses how improved this process would be.

Comment: Question...I understand that an SP would probably be better suited for this but still this should work even with in-line SQL. Anyone see anything that I'm doing incorrectly or maybe a way to improve the performance of bulk insert?

Comment: One thing, for start that you can do and I'm pretty sure you will get a much better performance is to create your connection outside of your foreach (now it is inside your method `UpdateDbWithEligibleHours`). The way you are doing right now for each iteration you are opening, executing and not closing the connection. Try: Open connection, foreach, execute current statement, end foreach, close connection. This could even be your problem. Try it and let me know.

Comment: Will do. Give me a little bit to get to it, get the changes in place, and then I'll run it and let you know. Thanks.